# why does my discord bot don't seem to hear?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Well, I would create a discord bot that will stock given data in a database, .then I began to learn js

Until now i haven't any problem and found a lot of help in the web, before to create the database i tried to show detected data on the console but now I'm blocked and can't understand by myself where is the problem.

here is my code

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const { promisify } = require('util')
    const sleep = promisify(setTimeout)
    require('dotenv').config();
        const BOT_TOKEN = '******'
    
    client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`The bot is now working !\n\n`);
    });

     client.on('message', async (receivedMessage) => {
    // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return;
    }

    const { author, content, channel } = receivedMessage;
    const { id } = author;
    const trimmedContent = content.trim();

    if (trimmedContent.startsWith('!ins')) {
            console.log('Inside ins');
            module.exports = {
            prefix: "!ins",
            fn: (msg) => {
                let application = {}
                let filter = (msg) => !msg.author.bot;
                let options = {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 15000
                };
                msg.member.send("nom ?")
                    .then(dm => {
                        // After each question, we'll setup a collector on the DM channel
                        return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
                    })
                    .then(collected => {
                        // Convert the collection to an array & get the content from the first element
                        application.name = collected.array()[0].content;
                        // Ask the next question
                        return msg.member.send("Parfait, maintenant votre mail ?")
                    })
                    .then(dm => {
                        return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
                    })
                    .then(collected => {
                        application.emailAddress = collected.array()[0].content;
                        return msg.member.send("Excellent. Enfin, quel est votre âge ?")
                    })
                    .then(dm => {
                        return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
                    })
                    .then(collected => {
                        application.pitch = collected.array()[0].content;
                        console.log(application)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });

        // client.login logs the bot in and sets it up for use. You'll enter your token here.
    client.login('   ');
```

The problem is that bot doesn't react to **!ins** command and on the console I only have the console.log 2 and 3

if you need any more info, feel free to ask them and thanks for taken time

Answer (score 0):

I do think that you should code your main structure like mine because yours is a bit messy.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const BOT_TOKEN = '...';

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`The bot is now working !\n\n`);
});

client.on('message', async (receivedMessage) => {
    // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return;
    }

    const { author, content, channel } = receivedMessage;
    const { id } = author;

    // Removes whitespace from both ends of a string, "I personally do like this"
    const trimmedContent = content.trim();

    if (trimmedContent.startsWith('!ins')) {
        console.log('Inside ins');
    }
});

client.login(BOT_TOKEN);

process.on('exit',  () => {
    client.destroy();
    console.log(`The bot is now disconnected !\n\n`);
});
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I'm sorry, at the beginning it wasn't as messy, I edited my code and retry, the bot doesn't answer and it seems to stuck inside ins